# How to correctly define stages & commands in buildspec.yml?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, gradle, aws-code-deploy

Currently, I'm looking forward to migrating my own-side project into AWS and I have already uploaded it into CodeCommit. The next step is to utilize CodePipeline & CodeBuild for build and testing purposes.

I have a simple microservices written in Java with this `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:4.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-spring-boot-application'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
}

group 'com.polubentcev.messenger'
version '1.0'

docker {
    springBootApplication {
        baseImage = 'openjdk:11-jre-slim'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

def messengerVersion = '1.0'
def springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.polubentcev.messenger:messenger-util-model:'+messengerVersion
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:'+springBootVersion
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:2.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:2.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:'+springBootVersion
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:'+springBootVersion
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2:2.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:'+springBootVersion
}
```

I would like to have a `buildspec.yml` file for CodeDeploy in order to run unit tests and build docker image from it.

Does anybody have any similar experience and can help me to create the file?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a buildspec.yml file I used in one project to build and push a Docker image to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/):

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - COMMIT_HASH="$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)"
      - IMAGE_TAG="${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}"
      - printenv

  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -f infrastructure/Dockerfile -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG

  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - export IMAGE_NAME='projectName'
      - export IMAGE_URI=$REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - "printf '[{\"name\":\"%s\",\"imageUri\":\"%s\"}]' \"$IMAGE_NAME\" \"$IMAGE_URI\" > imagedefinitions.json"


artifacts:
  files:
    - imagedefinitions.json
```

I hope it helps to get you started. You'll obviously need to modify it for your needs. Check the [buildspec syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax) if you want to add more phases.

I use the `aws/codebuild/docker:17.09.0` image for the CodeBuild project. I pass in the `$REPOSITORY_URI` environment variable from my CodePipeline. It looks something like `123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/projectName`.

The [imagedefinitions.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create.html#pipelines-create-image-definitions) is then use in later CodePipeline stages to deploy the image to Fargate.